# Custom configuration files are not resolved by Intellij Spring Framework

Tags: spring, maven, intellij-idea, properties-file, custom-configuration

Custom configuration files in seperate module are not resolved by Intellij and that prevents application to run via Spring run and makes all properties grayed out and not referenced.
But after I run it via Maven once, then Spring run works for some time. It was ok a month before but at some point it has broken.

Here is custom configuration folder:

[image]

PropertiesConfig(these files should not have been highligted because of not being resolved):

[image]

Properties file(properties are grayed out):

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to provide sample project example?

Comment: @y.bedrov There is topic about this on Intellij forums and new issue has been created. 
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/5055268381074-Custom-Configuration-Folder-is-not-shown-for-Spring-Boot-project?page=1#community_comment_5062394061202
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-292431